# Javascript multiple parameters for sorting

Tags: javascript

I have an array called `lunchbox` which contains items with ids. Two of these items have the same ID. What I want to do is first sort my array based on ID. Then, if the IDs are the same, then sort alphabetically.

My code returns `Tuna`, `Bread`, and `Apple` in that order. What I want is for it to return `Bread`, `Tuna`, `Apple`, in that order. Not sure how to proceed.

```js
var lunchbox = [
  { id: 0, name: "Tuna" },
  { id: 1, name: "Apple" },
  { id: 0, name: "Bread" }
]

lunchbox.sort(function(a, b){
  return a.id > b.id;
  if (a.id === b.id){
  return a.name > b.name;
  }
  else { return a.id > b.id; }
});

for (i = 0; i < lunchbox.length; i++){
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += "<p>"+lunchbox[i].name+"</p>";
}
```

```html
<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: remove the first `return` statement, keep the rest.

Comment: i dont know what that means. removing the first return statement disregards one of my parameters.

Comment: remove this line: `return a.id > b.id;`